# C#: How can I only return the first set of capital letter words from a string?

Tags: c#, parsing

If I wanted to parse back a string to only return the first all capital words in it how would I do that?

Example:

```
"OTHER COMMENTS These are other comments that would be here. Some more
comments"
```

I want to just return `"OTHER COMMENTS"`

- These first upper case words can be many and the exact count is
  unknown.
- There could be other words in the string after with all caps
  that I just want to ignore.

Comment: Even removing the first set of all capital letter words would work if that is easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Split` (to break the sentence into words), `SkipWhile` (to skip words that aren't all caps), `ToUpper` (to test the word against it's upper-case counterpart), and `TakeWhile` (to take all sequential upper-case words once one is found). Finally, these words can be re-joined using `Join`:

```
string words = "OTHER COMMENTS These are other comments that would be here. " + 
    "Some more comments";

string capitalWords = string.Join(" ", words
    .Split()
    .SkipWhile(word => word != word.ToUpper())
    .TakeWhile(word => word == word.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: I missed the SkipWhile(). This is the answer

Comment: Dang...great minds! I didn't see your `TakeWhile` answer until after I posted.

Comment: I didn't know Split takes 0 arguments?

Comment: @CaiusJard There is an overload that takes a `params char[] separator` argument which, if empty, splits on whitespace.

Comment: I think `.TakeWhile(word => word == word.ToUpper()` does the job already. It implicitly *skips* a word that contains non-uppercase chars.

Comment: @Jimi I believe TakeWhile starts out assuming the predicate is true and stops returning when it becomes false. If the predicate is false to begin with (example in a string like "lowercase UPPERCASE more lowercase") then it won't return anything. The SkipWhile is there to remove any initial lowercase words

Comment: Ah, yes, sure. I was referring to the question, where the OP says: *to only return the first all capital words*. I interpreted it as a specific pattern, where the uppercase words can only be at the beginning of the string and when a non-uppercase word is found, it stops parsing.

Comment: @Jimi my solution would work that way (without SkipWhile)

Comment: @djv Yes, I already explained what I meant. See the OP sample string and *These **first** upper case words can be many*. Then *There could be other words in the string **after** .* If the uppercase words are positioned at the beginning of the string only, then your code has the same result. If not, then it would fail. But, since the pattern and the OP description *seem* to imply that the strings to extract are all positioned at the beginning of the strings **and** there could be many to parse, *skipping* the `SkipWhile()` *could* provide an advantage (in timing). That comment was for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the string as an array of chars. To check if the char is uppercase, use Char.IsUpper https://www.dotnetperls.com/char-islower. So, in the loop you can say if its a char - set a flag that we started reading the set. Then add that char to a collection of chars. Keep looping and once it is no longer an upper case char and the flag is still true, break out of the loop. Then return the collection of chars as a string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Seems messy, but I dont think there is any easy way to do this haha

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "OTHER COMMENTS These are other comments that would be here. Some more comments";
var output = String.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').TakeWhile(w => w.ToUpper() == w));
```

Split it into words, then take words while the uppercase version of the word is the same as the word. Then combine them back with the space separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Regex`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
// The Regex pattern is any number of capitalized letter followed by a non-word character.
// You may have to adjust this a bit.
Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Z]+\W)+"); 
string s = "OTHER COMMENTS These are other comments that would be here. Some more comments";
MatchCollection m = r.Matches(s);
// Only return the first match if there are any matches.
if (m.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Matches(s)[0]);
}
```